# Problems with CSS floats in container div

Tags: css, css-float

I've got a page with one fixed column and one fluid. I'm trying to get the left column to auto-size and the right one stay fixed.

This is something I've done loads of times but on this site the left column contains lots of divs with floats that are affecting the right one.

Can anyone help me get the right column showing at the top, I'd really appreciate it.

The URL is http://www.giraffetest.co.uk/shop/c0/colour/gold/mf.html

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: My apologies - I just thought it would be better to link as the site has a lot of source code and it's probably better to see the whole thing rather than a load of text

Comment: You should provide the relevant code or perhaps an outline of your HTML with the relevant CSS float values. You shouldn't give *all* of it, just the part you need help with

Comment: If floats are affecting a column they shouldn't, you are probably facing a hasLayout-Problem: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look into the page code, but the problem could be something related to the #contenWrapper not having a width of 100% and the left column having a fixed margin.